# how often do we find $p^m - q^n= \pm2$ for primes $p,q$ and $m,n > 1$

Tags: prime-numbers

if one of the integers $m,n$ is $1$ it does not seem too difficult to find examples of odd primes satisfying:
$$|p^m-q^n| = 2$$ so suppose $\min(m,n)>1$, and call (just for the purpose of this question) primes satisfying the condition mentioned *complementary*. what can be asserted about the set of complementary primes? is such complementarity rare, or quite common?

Comment: How far have you looked for examples?  Do the pairs $(9,11),(23,25),(125,127)$ fit into your initial question?  (It is fairly frequent that there is a prime within distance $2$ on one side or the other of the square of a prime...)

Comment: It is commomplace to see "|" used where "\mid" should appear, but this was the opposite error.  I changed it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: what is the usual usage of "\mid"?

Comment: \mid is used in $\Pr(A\mid B)$ or $\{f(x)\mid x\in A\}$ or the like.  \mid provides spacing before it and after it, which would be absent if one were to write (as many here do) $\Pr(A|B)$ or $\{f(x)|x\in A\}$.  You wrote $\mid p^m-q^n\mid=2$.  I changed it to $|p^m-q^n|=2$.  Notice that the difference in appearance is conspicuous.

Comment: @abiessu yes I noticed that from a few examples. but not so obvious with the $m,n \gt 1$ condition. I haven't searched thoroughly - if there are any obvious examples they will surely be presented. but the question is of interest, e.g. in relation to the prime pairs question ($m=n=1$) (which, if it hasan't been shown yet, nevertheless, like the well-known Goldbach and Riemann conjectures, nearly everyone except professional contrarians or sceptics, thinks very probable)

Comment: @Michael thanks for that. although a slow learner I am very interested in questions of mathematical orthography. I am new to mathjax, and you can perhaps imagine what a wonderful liberation it is to be able to construct reasonable notation in this way.

Comment: abiessu $3^3+2 =29; 5^3+2 =127$

Comment: With the edit to your question, my examples are no longer relevant; the way it read initially, it seemed that you hadn't found examples for the case where exactly one of $m,n$ is $1$...

Comment: no problem with examples. it all helps develop the creative loam of the subconscious imagination. Dietrich's reference shows the gateway to answering this question, though as yet I lack the analytical equipment to enter through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Diophantine equation $p^m-q^n=c$ for given integers $p,q,c$ is called *Pillai's equation*.
Here one searches for positive integer solutions $m,n$.
There are many conjectures (and some results) on this equation. For example, Pillai conjectured that $3^m-2^n=c$ has at most one solution in positive integers for $|c|>13$. This was proved by Stroecker and Tijdeman in 1982. For more details see http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/B-Pillai.pdf.

What does this mean for our question, if $m,n>1$ are given ? As far as I can see, there are not many primes $p,q$ (I suppose that you want distinct primes) satisfying Pillai's equation with given exponents.